# Python SimpleHttpServer Background bug?

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

Using a very simple BaseHttpServer (code below) I am experiencing the following problem:

Starting the server in background using `./testserver.py &` works fine and the server responses on port 12121 . When I type in `disown` the server still responses. After closing the terminal the server stops after the next request with **Input/output error** in `test.log`

Steps to reconstruct:

```
$ ./testserver &
$ bg
$ disown
```

close terminal, send a request to server -> server does not respond.

The only solution I found was to redirect the `stdout` and `stderr`:
    $ ./testserver > /dev/null 2>&1
or as @Daniel Stated to call it the usual way with `nohup`

Has anyone experienced this bug before or why is this a desired behaviour for a HttpServer to crash if there is no output possible?

---

testserver.py

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import time
import BaseHTTPServer


HOST_NAME = '0.0.0.0'
PORT_NUMBER = 12121


class MyHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_HEAD(s):
        s.send_response(200)
        s.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        s.end_headers()
    def do_GET(s):
        """Respond to a GET request."""
        s.send_response(200)
        s.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        s.end_headers()
        s.wfile.write("MANUAL SERVER SUCCESS")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_class = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
    httpd = server_class((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER), MyHandler)
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except Exception as e:
        with open('test.log', 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(e))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only can write strings to files not exceptions. And you have to redirect `stdout` and `stderr` somewhere, otherwise any output will hang your program. Why don't you use `nohup`? That's the normal way, to start programs without terminal.

To make this clear: There is no special behavior in HttpServer. HttpServer is writing log-information to the terminal, so you need a terminal or a redirection to a file.

Comment: You 're right about both points, changed the code accordingly (just forgot that `write` does not take the `__str__` method. Then I'm indeed getting the `Input/outpu error` . The question still remains whether why it is a desired behaviour for a HttpServer to crash if there is no output possible